# Stop the webbrowser control auto-correcting URLs that the user types in

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

Background: 
We're using the webbrowser control in a windows forms .net 4 project.
This is to allow users to edit the text of html emails.

**Problem:**

Can we stop the webbrowser control auto-correcting text the user types in?
For example the user types the text `http://www.randomwebsite.com` then the web browser control "helpfully" wraps that text with an `<A> tag`.
I want to stop this behaviour if at all possible,

**The end game:**

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is to allow users to put a URL to an image in and use data tags from my system to fill in part of the URL. 
At the moment the user will have to go into a view source view and remove the A tags to get it to work, which is a very poor solution...

I can hear the support desk phones ringing already!!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the only solution I have found is to trap the `keyup` event, select the text using a `TextRange` and then use `ExecCommand("unlink")` to remove the automated link.

It has the disadvantage of being ugly as the link is shown then disappears but it does work.